# Can't run NativeScript app in Android emulator

Tags: nativescript

I run this command:

`tns run android --emulator`

And I get this error:

> Cannot find connected devices.
>   Emulator start failed with: Cannot run the app in the selected native emulator. Try to restart the adb server by running the `adb kill-server` command in the Command Prompt, or increase the allocated RAM of the virtual device through the Android Virtual Device manager. NativeScript CLI users can try to increase the timeout of the operation by adding the `--timeout` flag.
>   To list currently connected devices and verify that the specified identifier exists, run 'tns device'.
>   To list available emulator images, run 'tns device  --available-devices'.

I tried `adb kill-server` and that didn't help; I also tried the timeout thing with a setting of 60 and that didn't help either. I'm not sure how to access Android Virtual Device Manager to increase the allocated RAM. If I run `tns device --available-devices` I get a list of two emulated devices. How can I get the emulator set up so I can run my app?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Did you try launching the emulator manually and then run the tns command?

Comment: No, but when I try it now `emulator -avd android_accelerated_x86_oreo` I get this error: `PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`

Comment: I tried defining `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` as `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk` but now I get this error: `PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk]!`

Comment: Hmm, now I'm somehow getting a different error: `PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPU.`

Comment: does `tns doctor` give you any errors?

Comment: Did you find out what was the solution for this problem @ekolis ? I'm having this exact same problem

Comment: No, I never did, sorry - I was experimenting with a bunch of different mobile app frameworks and never got back to this one!